# Command to go to Normal-mode and Visual-mode (or exiting insert-mode) - pressing ESC without the escape-key

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode, escape

I'm working on a server, that I can only SSH into via a browser. In there, I have to edit some files.

The problem is, that let's say I go to INSERT MODE and write some text.
If I then want to go back to NORMAL MODE, then I would normally just press <kbd>ESC</kbd>. HOWEVER! When I do so, then the browser 'catches' the <kbd>ESC</kbd>-press and the SSH-session will become out-of-focus, and it'll stay in INSERT MODE.

So how do I go from INSERT MODE without the escape-key?

---

**Solution attempt 1 - `-- (insert) --`**

If I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> - then I can insert one command, before 'coming back' to insert mode. I could write `:wq` and then reopen the file afterwards. But I need to inject one big change at once, to several small ones (since it would leave the server in an error state).

**Solution attempt 2 - Other browser**

Try a different browser, didn't make any difference.

**Solution attempt 3 - `:set visualmode`**

I didn't find this anywhere - I'm simply grasping for straws. That command doesn't exist.

**Solution attempt 4 - Read this: [Avoid the escape key](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key)**

I read that once, but apparently too quickly. I found the answer there later.

---

### Specs

- The SSH-connection is to a server on AWS.
- I'm on a Macbook Pro (Big Sur).
- VIM-version 8.0 (2016, Sep 12)
- Fedora-Linux system.

Comment: Does `<C-[>` work?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was a mix between attempt 1 and 4.

### If you're stuck in INSERT MODE without escape

This procedure maps `jj` to the Escape-key.

**Step 1**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>   -> Goes to `-- (insert) --`-mode (where you can type a single command.

**Step 2**

Write: `:imap jj <Esc>` [Found here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key#Mappings)

... This maps (in insert mode) a double-press on `j` to an ESC.

**Step 3**

Press `jj`

:-)

---

### If you're stuck in VISUAL MODE or VISUAL LINE MODE without escape

This sends a bollocks-command, which won't compute and will get you back to Normal-mode.

**Approach**

Write: `:heyhomisterdj`

Vim will tell you, that you typed a non-existing command, *and take you back to NORMAL MODE*. Hah! Gotcha, Vim!